# java ee authentification users <-> roles many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication

I'd like to ask how to make users <-> roles many-to-many relationship in user authetification in java ee, using jsf and glassfish
Let's say that I have roles in system: admin, viewer, writer, reader, producent, consumer, philosopher. A user can have any of these roles (it can be selected using checkbox). As i have read Java EE 7 docs (maybe I have read them not well enough) I have come to the conclusion, that you can only have users <-> roles many-to-one relationship, at least using JDBC realm. Is it true?
If yes how to solve my problem? Do I need to get user login from session context and look for that user's roles in database?

Comment: Which Java EE 7 doc are you referring to?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/JEETT.pdf Part X - Security, but I may have misunderstood something. Do you know how to make user belong to many groups in Java EE authorization with use of JDBC?

Comment: Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7693/beaxg/index.html) says that you can map a role to more groups.

Comment: If i ever met you remember I have to buy you a beer.